# installer project / installutil.exe dll

Tags: windows-installer, installutil

I have a simple C# project generating a MMC Snapin DLL file from a project A, and would like to know how to use Installer Project to "register" (doing what installutil.exe) the DLL file.

Can someone point me to an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The general way installer classes work is that if you're in development mode you run InstallUtil.exe, but if you're in deployment mode with a setup project you just add the Dll as a custom action to all the nodes of the Custom Action in the install (Install, Rollback, Commit, Uninstall).